# Cell is not being rendered in UITableView after insert/delete cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview which can work in 2 modes: read-only and read-write. In read-only mode table contains only 4 cells, in read-write mode - 8 cells. To transit between these 2 modes I have button with implemented action:

```
...
NSArray* cellIndexesInCurrentMode = [self cellIndexesInMode:Mode1];
NSArray* cellIndexInNewMode = [self cellIndexesInMode:Mode2];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: cellIndexInNewMode withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:cellIndexesInCurrentMode withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Everything works fine, until I scroll table down in read-write (8-cells), so it bounced up. After that, tapping on the button to transit to mode2 leads to situation when one of the cells are not renderred:

```
                 before transition:
```

[image: before transition:]

```
                 after transition:
```

[image: after transition:]

My investigation showed that for some reason this cell has alpha = 0 after the last layoutSubviews call on UITableView.

I am stuck, I have no idea what is going on, so any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView :(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)cellForRowAtIndexPath {
    IDataSourceElement item = [[self collection] getDataSourceElementAtIndex:cellForRowAtIndexPath.row];

```
MyTableCell* cell = nil;

if ([item conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyTableCellBuilder)]) {
    cell = [(MyTableCellBuilder)item tableView:tableView buildCellForIndexPath:cellForRowAtIndexPath];
} 

if (cell == nil) {
    Class cellClass = [self getCellClassForElement: item];

    NSString* reuseId = [cellClass description];

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[cellClass alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier :reuseId] autorelease];
    }
}


[self fillCell:cell forTableView:tableView forIndexPath:cellForRowAtIndexPath];

return cell;
```

}

And MyTableCellBuilder buildCellForIndexPath: method implementation

```
- (MyTableCell*) tableView :(UITableView*)tableView buildCellForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)buildCellForIndexPath {
    MyTableCell* cell = myTableCell;
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TextPropertyCell class]] == NO) {
        cell = (MyTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier :[self cellReuseIdentifier]];
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MyTableCell class]] == NO) {
            cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier :[self cellReuseIdentifier]] autorelease];
        }
        [self prepareCell:cell];
    }

        //cell setup
        ...
    ...
    return cell;
}
```

My idea was that the problem with caching instance of UITableViewCell, I know that it is not best way to do, but anyway I had it. I tried to remove caching, so all I did I set myTableCell to nil, so it is never returned from this method. And... it helped! I don't know why and would really like to know the answer?

Comment: when the alpha is set to 0, it's hidden/invisible... set alpha to 1.. to make it visible again.

Comment: :) thanks, but I want to know why it is set to 0 at first place

Answer (score 0):

show your cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation, i'm sure that's where you should look for mistake.

Comment: It is hard to show cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation, because it quite complex, I updated question with code that is similar to real.